# AVL Tree Delete in C

Tags: c, avl-tree

I have an AVL Tree implementation that can successfully build a tree by insertions. Rotations etc. also work fine. However my delete function has problems. It poorly balances and sometimes crashes. To me, the rotations make sense (I've commented appropriate places) but somehow it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

```
void delete_elem(node** t, int val, uint delete_flag) {
    if(!(*t))
        return;
    if((*t)->data < val)
        delete_elem(&(*t)->right, val, delete_flag);
    else if((*t)->data > val)
        delete_elem(&(*t)->left, val, delete_flag);
    else {                                                                  // found elem
                                                                            // if there's a duplicate, remove it
        if(delete_flag == DELETE_NO_FORCE && (*t)->dup_count)   {
            --(*t)->dup_count;
            printf("Duplicate element removed. %d left.\n", (*t)->dup_count);
        }
        else {                                                              // there were no duplicates
            node* del;
            if(!(*t)->left && (*t)->right) {                                // no left but right
                del = (*t);
                (*t) = (*t)->right;
                free(del);
            }
            else if(!(*t)->right && (*t)->left) {                           // no right but left
                del = (*t);
                (*t) = (*t)->left;
                free(del);
            }
            else if(!(*t)->left && !(*t)->right) {                          // additionally, you can use the is_leaf function we wrote before, in here
                free(*t);
                *t = NULL;
            }
            else {                                                          // has both children
                del = get_successor(*t, *t);                                // get the in-order successor in tree *t of *t
                printf("succ of %d is %d.\n", (*t)->data, del->data);
                (*t)->data = del->data;                                     // swap the successor's data with t's data
                (*t)->dup_count = del->dup_count;                           // IMPORTANT! We support duplicates! Duplicate count must also be swapped!
                delete_elem(&(*t)->right, del->data, DELETE_FORCE);         // We must now delete this guy forcefully!
            }

            if(!(*t))                                                       // if t was deleted and not needed anymore, don't bother. Update height if it exists
                return;

            (*t)->height = Max(get_height((*t)->left), get_height((*t)->right)) + 1;
            int bfactor = get_balance(*t);

            if(bfactor > 1 && get_balance((*t)->left) > 0)
                rotate_once_right(t);
            else if(bfactor > 1 && get_balance((*t)->left) < 0)
                rotate_twice_left(t);
            else if(bfactor < -1 && get_balance((*t)->right) > 0)
                rotate_once_left(t);
            else if(bfactor < -1 && get_balance((*t)->right) < 0)
                rotate_twice_right(t);
        }
    }
}
```

The above is my delete function.

The following are some screenshots of the crash occuring:

[image: Initial Tree]

[image: After first Deletion]

[image: Crash after 2nd Deletion]

These are my rotation functions. They seem to be working right, as everytime I create a tree, it's always reported to be an AVL Tree. However, just in case:

```
void rotate_once_left(node** k1) {
    node* temp = (*k1)->left;
    (*k1)->left = temp->right;
    temp->right = *k1;

    (*k1)->height = Max(get_height((*k1)->left), get_height((*k1)->right)) + 1;
    temp->height = Max(get_height(temp->left), (*k1)->height) + 1;

    *k1 = temp;
}

void rotate_once_right(node** k1) {
    node* temp = (*k1)->right;
    (*k1)->right = temp->left;
    temp->left = *k1;

    (*k1)->height = Max(get_height((*k1)->left), get_height((*k1)->right)) + 1;
    temp->height = Max(get_height(temp->right), (*k1)->height) + 1;

    *k1 = temp;
}

void rotate_twice_left(node** k1) {
    rotate_once_right(&(*k1)->left);
    rotate_once_left(k1);
}

void rotate_twice_right(node** k1) {
    rotate_once_left(&(*k1)->right);
    rotate_once_right(k1);
}
```

Update: No more crash, but some unbalance is left after deletion. Sample test case:

[image: This worked]
[image: This didn't work]

Comment: There are a few tests in the rebalancing code that are comparing whether the height difference is `>=` a negative value. Shouldn't those be `<=`?

Comment: That helped, although it's still not balanced all the time. What happens is this: More often than not, when I delete the root, it's balanced. However sometimes it fails the AVL check and is reported to be unbalanced. Now I'm thinking my rotations calls might be the wrong ones. Still no idea what the problem actually is, though. I've updated the OP to reflect the change you suggested.

Comment: I've also managed to simplify down the long checks. They are more condensed now. Still, the problem remains. I'll put screenshots of a case that is unbalanced in the OP.

Comment: I didn't read your code thoroughly but when a node has two children you seem to always delete its right child (delete_elem(&(*t)->right, del->data, DELETE_FORCE);)

Comment: That is to find the successor in the right subtree and delete it. The reason is because we carried it up to the root, so it's a duplicate now.

Comment: I've written an AVL years ago, it's quite ugly but it works. You can take a look at it if you're interested: https://gist.github.com/martinkunev/720386

Comment: That's an interesting implementation, but I'm looking for a much simpler one. The way it seems, you didn't do much different than I did. I really can't see my mistake, and I bet it's a small mistake like the operator one Ian Abbott pointed out.

Comment: Remember how I said I knew it'd be a silly mistake again? Check where my brackets are... None of the intermediary nodes were being updated...